# DJANGO how to make boolean field (True/False) display "Available / Not Available" in View?

Tags: django

My code in Django:

> class Product(models.Model):
>
> ```
> available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
> ```

My code in HTML:

```
{% for product in products %}
    <li>
    <a href="{% url 'product_detail' product.id %}">
        {{ product.name }}{{ product.price }}{{ product.available }}
    </a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [the built-in `yesno` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#yesno).

```
{{ product.available|yesno:"Available,Not Available" }}
```